# is the below expression a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $f(t), g(t), h(t)\in \mathbb F_{q}[t]$. Let $F(t)=f(t)+g(t)h(t)^{2}$. Is $F(t)$ a polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[t]$ or is it a function?

Please help

Comment: If $f(t), g(t), h(t) \in \mathbb F_q[t]$, then so is $F(t)$.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Lack of knowledge is not an eligibility criteria for asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is both a polynomial and a function. We are given that $f(t),g(t),h(t)$ are polynomials, and the set of polynomials is closed under sums and products; therefore $F(t)$ is also a polynomial. And any polynomial can be considered a function as well, namely the function $F\colon \Bbb F_q\to\Bbb F_q$ given by $a \mapsto F(a)$.

Comment: Though be aware that over a finite field, there can be two polynomials which are different when considered as polynomials, but which give the same function.

Comment: The question was clear in the context, but still people downvote. I do not understand the logic

Comment: Also, every function from a finite field into itself is a polynomial function.